# Style the MaterialBetterSpinner in Android

Tags: android, styles, material-design, spinner

I create a form in my android app and I use `material.MaterialBetterSpinner`. How can i remove or change the color of the border at bottom in `MaterialBetterSpinner` when it is in normal state and focus state?

code:

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPro"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Select Project"
                    app:met_floatingLabel="normal"/>
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEgUK.png)

Comment: Can you add an image showing what you currently have?

Comment: i checked the code for MaterialBetterSpinner and the developer is using AutoCompleteTextView to show the dropdown. you need to create a style that will replace the color. As far as I know, it is not available out of the box

Comment: thats the link of the sample image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEgUK.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem
https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/wiki

thank you for help..!! :)